# What is this symbol called: “¶”

Tags: punctuation, symbols

I'm trying to find out what this symbol means and if it has a name:

> ## ¶

I've seen it being used in word processors.

Comment: Voting to reopen. While the question can be easily answered with a single link, it's essentially impossible to *find* that link unless you already know the answer.

Comment: @JSBngs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/¶

Comment: @Cerberus It's surprising to see that that actually works, and it's not at all obvious that you can look up punctuation marks that way.

Comment: I didn't know I could search wikipedia for a symbol. Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's called a *[pilcrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow)*.

From Wikipedia:

> The *pilcrow* (¶), also called the *paragraph mark*, *paragraph sign*, *paraph*, *alinea* (Latin: *a lineā*, "off the line"), or *blind P*, is a typographical character commonly used to denote individual paragraphs.

Comment: Unicode has three related code points: ¶ U+00B6 PILCROW SIGN, ⁋ U+204B REVERSED PILCROW SIGN, and ❡ U+2761  CURVED STEM PARAGRAPH SIGN ORNAMENT.

Comment: If you call it a pilcrow, very few people will know what you mean, unfortunately :( Better to call it a paragraph sign.

Comment: @Mark Beadles, very good point. I actually searched Google for "Paragraph sign" to find the answer, so I'd agree it's the more common parlance.

Comment: for what it's worth, in LaTeX it is `\textparagraph` which supports the "paragraph" moniker